# cURL reporting self-signed cert is not valid

Tags: apt, curl, certificates

I am trying to use some tools to manage various devices, and found that I can no longer connect to anything running a webserver.

Some troubleshooting later found cURL kicking this error.

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html
curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

I have gone to the site, and installed a root cert I pulled for GlobalSign and placed it in /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ with a .CRT extension.

However updating the cert, it claims it was skipped because it was a duplicate. I have attempted to force update all the certs via apt-get, and with:

```
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

To no effect. I am trying to understand this problem, but I am afraid it makes no sense to me. I never self-signed a certificate directly, so it couldnt have expired unless generated by the system. Even then, updating the root certificates should have resolved that.

Would someone be able to give a suggestion on the next step I can take to resolve this? Unfortunately the product I need to use is not cURL which means I cannot simply disregard this alert. I would also prefer not to globally disregard certificate verification either as one suggestion I found was.

Comment: Does the site in question actually have a self-signed certificate or not? Because if it does, any update of public root certificates doesn't make sense, as they have nothing to do with the self-signed certificate in question.

Comment: I am an idiot. Its likely the far end. I tested by cURLing a set of public sites and those work. 

Is there an easy way I can default to ignoring certificate authentication system-wide, then?

Comment: Hm... I don't know of any. As far as I know, it can only be done per application.